# Why is mouse_event deprecated?

Tags: c#, windows, mouseevent

I'm currently following a guide to me a simple Auto Clicking application. The guide I'm using utilizes `mouse_event`.

Everywhere I look says that `mouse_event` is **deprecated** and that it is better to use `SendInput`, but I have yet to find an actual reason why you should use one over the other.

Even the documentation on [mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states "Use SendInput instead."

Most of my experience is in java and I am very familiar with thread.stop() being deprecated because it is dangerous. I'm looking for the same type of explanation.

Comment: `SendInput` is more general, better documented, although I don't like some functions to be called `deprecated`, such as the `GetScrollPos` function, if we just need to get the position of scrollbar, using it will be  very helpful and simple, but they say it's intended to be obsolete and that we should use `GetScrollInfo` instead. `GetScrollInfo` is a little complicated with the `SCROLLINFO` structure.

Comment: @KingKing So does that mean that mouse_event and SendInput simulate mouse input the same way?

Comment: I think so, they have the same functionality in **mouse input**, but `SendInput` can also handle **keyboard input**, that's why I said `SendInput` is more general. I think `SendInput` = `mouse_event` + `keybd_event` + (maybe more).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
VOID WINAPI mouse_event(
  _In_  DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_  DWORD dx,
  _In_  DWORD dy,
  _In_  DWORD dwData,
  _In_  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo
);
```

That's the declaration for mouse_event().  After you've done some winapi programming then it will become starkly obvious what is wrong with this function.  *It doesn't have any way to indicate failure*.  The keybd_event() function has the same problem.  You can for example pass junk values for dwFlags and it just won't work without any way to find out why.

Almost all winapi functions have a return value, BOOL or HANDLE is typical.  Which lets the function report failure.  You typically call GetLastError() next to find out what went wrong.

Like SendInput() does.

Comment: Looks like you're expert in win32, could you predict how long the `mouse_event` (and other the so-called obsolete functions) can be able to use/declare/import from *dll*? thank you.

Comment: It is never going to go away, too many old programs depend on it.  A good opportunity would have been dropping it for x64.  They didn't.

Comment: None that I can think of, backwards compatibility is sacred in Windows.  Writing programs that fail in an undiagnosable way is still supported :)

Answer (score 1):

A **mouse_event** inmediatly makes you think about a device that has a mouse and not all them do.

So when you think about any device that can handle touch gestures, as many mobile and tablet , is much better to have a class that represents them; it also probably keeps the developer thinking about all the other kind of Inputs that it needs to handle or send to make work on as many devices as posible

Comment: It didn't occur to me to think of it that way. SendInput sounds much more organic when described that way. I forget how much user input has changed in the past 14 years.