# Python detecting and moving mouse

Tags: python

So, I'm making a script using the mouse when both LMB and RMB are clicked, the mouse will move down a certain amount. The issue I'm running into is when I try to move the mouse. As soon as I place the win32api line in, the command prompt freezes after printing the first time. I've attempted to do this with a bunch of other python libraries either resulting in the same issue, or simply not working at all (due to the application being fullscreen). If you commented the win32api line, it would print for the duration of both buttons pressed.

I'd like to fix the freezing issue if possible.

Libraries tried:

- PyAutoGui
- win32api
- mouse
- pynput
- pydirectinput

```
while True:
  if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(1) < 0 and win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(2) < 0:
    print("Both pressed")
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 1, 0 ,0)
    print("this never gets printed")
```

Comment: Does the `mouse_event` line ever work in any circumstances? If you run it every second, for instance, does it work? Although apparently it's a deprecated function, maybe look into the suggested alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576776/why-is-mouse-event-deprecated/18577029

Comment: @RandomDavis Thanks for your input. It has worked outside of the while loop, and works inside the loop the very first time. I've looked into SendInput but frankly can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: NOTE: Just tried it with SendInput...same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
import win32api
import win32con

def move(x,y):
    if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(1) < 0 and win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(2) < 0:
        print("Both pressed")
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0 ,0)
        print("moved")
    else:
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:  # making a loop
        move(0, 500)
        try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
            if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
                print('You Pressed A Key!')
                break  # finishing the loop
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            break
```

or check this one that moves the mouse 1 pixel at a time:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
import win32api
import win32con
import time

def move(x,y):
    if x is None or x == 0:
        x = 0
    if y is None or y == 0:
        y = 1
    if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(1) < 0 and win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(2) < 0:
        print("Both pressed")
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0 ,0)  # | win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE
        print("moved")
    else:
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:  # making a loop
        move(0, 0)
        #time.sleep(1)
        try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
            if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
                print('You Pressed A Key!')
                break  # finishing the loop
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            break
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @zooid. I'm curious to see your results from this. When I test it, I get the same freeze.

Comment: what is it that you test @Russell? Save the code posted above (use the 2nd example) to something.py. Then run from cmd with the syntax `python.exe something.py`. A console will open and when you click both buttons the mouse will start moving down. It will keep the terminal open until you press 'q' on the keyboard.

Comment: @Russell watch my result here https://youtu.be/VW410jFyf-s

Comment: I appreciate that thanks. I run with both VS Code & cmd prompt. I am experienced user, fear not. I wonder if it's an issue with my computer, or the version of python (3.9). What's your version? let me test on another computer @zooid

Comment: did you try with my complete code or just picked some pieces and put them in your loop? My experience with "while loops" are not good. You have to implement an escape option. This is what I think your problem is. Usually while loops without escape lead to interpreter crushing.

Comment: I straight copy and pasted your code into a fresh python file and tried it out. Perhaps it's the python version or simply my computer.

Comment: So I actually fixed the issue by changing computers...not sure what the problem was with my other computer but oh well. I appreciate the help.